# How to manage react application while using two template

Tags: node.js, reactjs, native, mern

I am creating an ecommerce website, with template for admin panel and user-panel, both template are diffrents. So my problems is how can i set layout in public. for example if set both links on index.html them admin panel and user panel will be clash. So what i can do else

I tried to create diffrent layout in public, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can manage multiple templates using React. Below is the details.
Suppose you have User Panel & Admin Panel. You can define there routes in separate files. Like you will create a **components/routes** folder. And inside **UserRoutes.ts & AdminRoutes.ts**

```
const routes = [
{ path: "/change-password", component: ChangePassword, type: "user" },
{ path: "/user-dashboard", component: UserDashboard, type: "user" },
{ path: "/admin-dashboard", component: Dashboard, type: "admin" },
{ path: "/setting", component: Setting, type: "admin" },
];
```

Now create `ProtectedRoute.ts` file and paste below code in it.

```
const ProtectedRoute: FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({component: Component,type,...rest
}) => {
const authUser = useSelector(selectAuthUser);
const redirectTo = type === "admin" ? "/admin-login" : "/login";
if (!isLoggedIn || authUser.type !== type) {
 return <Redirect to={redirectTo} />;
}
return <Component {...rest} />;
};
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

In your `App.ts` file.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin-login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      {routes.map((route) => {
        return (
          <ProtectedRoute
            key={route.path}
            path={route.path}
            component={route.component}
            type={route.type}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

This will implement your basic routing and navigation. Now you can separate your component as below, You can change the name or structure according to your need.

```
- src
  - modules
    - admin-modules
      - AdminDasboard.tsx
    - user-modules
      - UserDashboard.tsx
```

I hope this will help in your problem.

Thank you

Comment: You may not have fully grasped my question, and I apologize for any lack of clarity. To clarify, I have a public index.html file that serves as the default layout for all routes in my project. However, what I require is separate HTML files for the admin and user sections, each with different CSS linkages. You might wonder why I can't simply include all the CSS links in the index.html file. The reason for this is the potential for CSS conflicts that can arise.